# Unable to run exe file created by pyinstaller, showing error "google-api-python-client was not found"

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, google-api-python-client

I am trying to convert a python script to .exe that uses the keys.json file to run.
When I try to run the .exe file I get an error and the window closes automatically in 1-2 seconds.

I'm completely lost, I tried some solutions available on the internet but nothing is working, I'm very upset.

My .spec file looks like,

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

    block_cipher = None


    a = Analysis(['SMIDST.py'],
                 pathex=['D:\\code\\SBF Interns APP\\SMIDST'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[('keys.json', '.')],
                 hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn', 'googleapiclient', 'apiclient'],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              a.binaries,
              a.zipfiles,
              a.datas,
              [],
              name='SMIDST',
              debug=False,
              bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              upx_exclude=[],
              runtime_tmpdir=None,
              console=True )
```

Please help me, Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Run your exe from the commandline - do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I got this error, `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMIDST.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "google\oauth2\service_account.py", line 233, in from_service_account_file
  File "google\auth\_service_account_info.py", line 72, in from_filename
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keys.json'
[16880] Failed to execute script SMIDST`

Comment: And I already have the keys.json file in the main folder as well as in the dist folder, also I copied google-api-python-client folder in both but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the file read function to embed the file manualy? If it works maybe it cant find the file. To solve that problem you can try copying the exe to where you main funciton or where you command line sits when its run(pwd path)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, I'm very new to programming and hence, I'm unable to understand you. Can you please simplify a bit?